# I need to make an exponential calculator, but it can only handle up to 20^15, how can It handle more?

Tags: c++

```
//This is my code so far
//It is in microsoft studio visual

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int a, b;

 cout << "Input a whole number:"; //The following lines are to make it interactive
 cin >> a;
 cout << "Input a whole number:";
 cin >> b;

 int result = 1;
 for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
     result *= a;

 cout << "The Answer is:" << result;
 cout << "\n";
 system("PAUSE");
}
//How do I expand the power of it to handle more?
```

I just need to increase the power of it to handle more. I need this for a class and I can't  quite figure it out. I met the qualifications, but I want it to be more powerful.

Comment: ***How do I expand the power of it to handle more?*** Use a big integer library.

Comment: Here is one: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html

Comment: Here is a second option: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: See this: [http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

Comment: Use ```long long``` instead of ```int```